# How I reached this many people in very short period

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, people-reached

Here's my [Stack Overflow Profile.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936696/rahul-nikate) Couple of days back people reached was showing **~17K** in my profile and today it is showing **~173k** people reached.

How did I reach so many people in very short period?

However I don't have proof showing **17K** reached before couple of days.

Comment: You might have answered a question that had a lot of views. I believe all views on that question would count for your number, even if they were before you posted your answer.

Comment: @RetoKoradi If this is the case then it's wrong count. It should count views for me from the point I answered it question.

Comment: @Rahul, This is a known problem that it does not. I believe that SE devs have said that it won't be fixed.

Comment: @JonasCz Do you have any source for it. I'll be glad to see it.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244538/289005), and also the details on how it is calculated (in the question), as well as the first comment on the question. See the answer below (on your question) for why it wont be fixed.

Comment: *"it's wrong count"* - more or less inevitably, yes! How could SO possibly figure out who had *actually read* your answers? They might scroll past without reading, leave it in view while actually in another tab, ...

Comment: Check this [data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/320082/view-counts-on-my-answers?UserId=3936696), you likely got an upvote recently on one of those top 2 answers.

Comment: @Rahul [Proof with the WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150527110532/http://stackoverflow.com/users/3936696/rahul-nikate)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I went through your answers and found out that the key point here is [this answer you posted on Apr 10th](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554589/1983854) in "Call a stored procedure with parameter in c#".

This question has 157K views and 3 visible answers. Since your score is 1, you qualify to get its views into your counter.

From [Oded's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295446/1983854), this is what you accomplish:

- **Answers**

  - Non-deleted AND
  - Score > 0 AND
  - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:

    - In the top 3 answers

Checking the [timeline of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7542517/timeline) I see you got a +1 on May 22th. But why didn't you get the credit by then? Well, because there was [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26353407/1983854) having score 2.

But then that answer got deleted yesterday at 17h by Brad Larson:

> [image]

So this lead your answer to become part of the "top 3".

Comment: So does that mean that if someone posts another answer and gets more upvotes, OP's stat will go down 150k? This will either become an emotional roller-coaster or a good thing to hide with a user script =|

Comment: Why was that answer deleted by a moderator?

Comment: @Lightness Because the link included in that answer is spam.

Comment: @AlexisKing: No it's not

Comment: Still no reason for a moderator to delete it

Answer (score 25):

The value is fuzzy and is designed as such. The method for reaching this value is:

- **Questions**

  - Non-deleted only
- **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:

  - Non-deleted AND
  - Score > 0 AND
  - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:

    - In the top 3 answers OR
    - Is the Accepted Answer OR
    - Score >=5 OR
    - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

We do not have the data to make the value more accurate (and even if we had it, it would be much too expensive to query for every profile).

Comment: Yes agree with you. It's too expensive to get exact count.

Comment: Can you clarify how this could lead to a sudden jump as described in the question?   Is it something like "you must have supplied an answer that suddenly crossed the threshold described above, on a highly viewed question"?

Comment: @GreenAsJade - yes, essentially. Similarly, if you supplied an answer to a highly viewed question that no longer meets the criteria (say it got downvoted or another answer pushed it out of the top 3 answers), the value could drop.

Comment: Somebody should rename "people reached" to "people reached, or not. We don't have the data for that. Actually, we don't know, it might be completely false."

Comment: */me slaps @Canon with a cheerful trout.*

Comment: If you would store "the number of views to a question until the answer was posted" to the answer, I think it wouldn't cost that much more in addition to checking if the answer is qualified or not. The result would be much more accurate, but still fuzzy.

Comment: To quote Jeff Atwood, "If I have learned anything from the Internet, it is this: be very, very careful when you put a number next to someone's name. Because people will do whatever it takes to make that number go up." -- http://blog.codinghorror.com/because-reading-is-fundamental-2/

Comment: @canon Sure. If they would add that data you could set this value for each "old" answer to zero. Or to a percentage of the total count depending on the dates question and answer were posted. Its all fuzzy but more accurate :)

Comment: @canon Looks ok. 1.5 month old answer on a 4 years old question with 157k views. it is more realistic than 150k isn't it?

Comment: @canon I see your point. But at the moment it is even worse. And also a viewer of the question does not necessary read all the answers. Maybe the number should be changed to "people reached since we have data to calculate a not that fuzzy number"?

Answer (score 2):

*People reached* is a weird number anyway. You cannot possibly measure whether someone actually *read* your answer. So this number basically tells you the number of views on questions to which you have contributed "something relevant". In that regard, the number may be quite interesting to have even though it's a very rough estimate.

There is some issue though that can cause big changes in the number of people reached, as was already explained very well by the other answers.

But those big changes happen when you either answer a very old question, or your very old answer suddenly becomes more relevant. The latter may be caused by votes on your answer, or (in this case) by a mod suddenly deleting another, higher voted answer. And if this happens, it also has to happen in a question with a lot of views, otherwise it still won't cause a very big change.

Whatever the case, I think these situations are rare. Most answers are given a short time after the question is posted <sup>(citation needed)</sup>. Answers 4 years after are not that common, and neither are big shifts in the ranking after such a long time, so I think the number will be more reliable for others, and you just happen to be an exception.

That said, it would be nice if the number got a little bit more precise, if only if it could count just the number of visits the question has had since your answer (regardless of your rank at the time of visit) it would be better, and maybe possible to calculate with the current server capacity.

Fortunately, this is something that may be improved over time, and the ranking may become more precise on each iteration. For now, let's just enjoy this feature as it is and take it with a due grain of salt.

Comment: "Mostly reliable, kinda, within a factor of five or so, except for the times it's way way off, which are impossible to distinguish on the surface" is not a particularly convincing argument for the worth of a statistic.

Comment: Is it a statistic? It's not by far as accurate as other numbers, but it doesn't pretend to be. Hovering the number, you get a clear description of how the estimate is calculated. Would an extra disclaimer be helpful? *"Warning, this number can be very inaccurate"*.