# Why does the number of "people reached" go down?

Tags: discussion, support

The count of "people reached" in my main user profile is ½ the total from the day before. What factors can make this number decrease?

Comment: I'm assuming you contributed to posts that were closed/deleted and they no longer count towards your "reached" score

Comment: Some questions about this kind of thing over on meta.stackexchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295446/2607247) on MSE from Oded has the criteria for the views on a post to count toward "People Reached". One of your posts must no longer meet the criteria.

Comment: FWIW, since I haven't been actively participating very long, it didn't take long to check all the posts in which I asked or answered, and I didn't see any that were closed/deleted.

Comment: I had 70K impact and now its 16K. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a post is no longer eligible for being included in the count, the number can go down.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) for details on the calculations:

- **Questions**

  - Non-deleted only
- **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:

  - Non-deleted AND
  - Score > 0 AND
  - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:

    - In the top 3 answers OR
    - Is the Accepted Answer OR
    - Score >5 OR
    - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

So, if a question was deleted, or an answer was deleted or got a score less than 1 or dropped off one of the top 3 (other answers are now in the top 3) or is no longer an accepted answer or its score is no longer > 5 or has less than 20% of the total vote count (other answers got more votes)...

There are many ways for the number to drop (though usually, not drastically).

The number is a very rough estimate.

Comment: That's the answer, one of my answers had a score of 1 but was down voted to 0. Thank you for the information. I searched for this question on SO Meta but couldn't find one.