# How did I impact ~1 million users in a single day?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I last checked my profile probably yesterday, the impact was around **~44k**. Below screenshot is my current profile statistics.

[image: 1.1 million impact]

How is it possible to impact so many users in a single day? I assume this is a *bug between main and meta site* since meta shows that I have reached **0** people (now increased due to this question) although I have answered two questions which have some up votes too. Are the answers not included in the impact score for the meta?

---

Going through the answers, it indeed seems like a false metric and the score is exaggerated. Probably this meta question could be turned to a feature request for finding difference between answer views from the date it was posted.

**Edit:**
Tunaki deleted his answer but it was worth to answer my question as it contains the **reasoning**. I will just leave the reasoning here.

[image: Tunaki's answer]

Comment: Yes, but this only leaves way to implement addition of average views/day system.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know the giant asteroid from Armageddon was on SO.

Comment: [Same Happened to me also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295440/how-i-reached-this-many-people-in-very-short-period)

Comment: We need to demote our pride. (I also impacted 1M, which seems too much for me.) Lets cut down those numbers!

Comment: @canon Nah, it is a great stat. Just count all those fine hours all users have spend on this. This is what keeps us occupied. We need more stats like this. (I might be bored, or weekend, or both)

Comment: @canon what would you expect from data that is not there? If people would see it as a gadget instead of something useful (like that it is a stat) would be the best option.

Comment: @canon I think we have to wait for the documents to be de-classified to fully understand what happened here...that takes 60 to 80 years...

Answer (score 29):

This smells fishy.  *Really* fishy.

Let's list the things that we know.

- The question was asked back in 2009, so it's over [6 and a half years old](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%28June+5%2C+2009+-+today%29), or ~2378 days.
- The question is ***very*** popular, with over 1M views.
- The answer didn't exist until 17 August, which is only [114 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%2817+August+2015+-+today%29), or 4% of the entire lifespan of the question.

Let's list some likelihoods.

- The question *most likely* had the majority of those views early on in its life.  A lazy estimate would put the total of views per day at [around 446 views/day](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1062057+views+%2F+%28June+5%2C+2009+-+today%29).  I don't believe it's possible to get snapshots of each individual day's views, but if anyone *can* I'd love to see that too.

The issue here is that you've managed to surge ahead with the supposition that you've helped over a million people with that *one* answer, when the likelihood is that you've helped closer to 40-50K.

This is why I feel like it's a bug.  The amount of time the answer has survived is no indicator of how many people have seen that specific answer.  Unfortunately, SEDE doesn't track views on a specific answer, but perhaps they should to come up with a more accurate answer on this.

This opens up this number (which is already flimsy) to be gamed; simply post a good answer on an old question and you count as "reaching" everyone that's viewed that question, even if they haven't viewed your answer.

---

In case my proposed solution wasn't quite clear, here's what I'm thinking.

The "reached" count you get should only increase based on the estimate of how long the answer was around with respect to the question's views.

Algebraically, it's "simply":

(total question views / total question life in days) * (total answer life in days)

For this case, it would be:

(1062111 views / 2378 days) * (114 days) ~ 50.9K people reached

This would make it more balanced towards answers who've existed more towards the length of the question and those that just showed up.  It's still a guess since that doesn't even come close into taking into account votes, but I doubt that would factor heavily into it, considering that the answer has to *exist* before it can be voted on.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug simply because it's working exactly as intended. However it is definitely a *faulty metric*, deciding to calculate it that way. It's definitely possible to calculate how many views a question has received since your answer and sum all of those up to get a more accurate "People Reached" number.

Comment: I'm more calling out the fact that the metric is faulty.  The code itself is doing what it's told, but the metric is woefully skewed.

Comment: Yes, the impact score is exaggerated, false and should not be counted as it is. There should be some difference between the views for various answer dates.

Comment: @pnuts:  This is a logical bug.  Even though it's being told this information, the information doesn't seem right.  It's kind of like...integer division, if you want to put a finer point on it...

Comment: When I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30881893/4099593) answer on a 88k times viewed question, the "helped" count went from 13k to 180k. Given that the question has 1m views, the calculation may be correct. (I am not sure tho) :/

Comment: @BhargavRao: The calculation may be more conservative, but we've not seen a case which involved such a popular question before.  At least, none spring to mind.

Comment: Yep true. On a lighter note, People with more "helped" count usually have more Necromancer badges :)

Comment: What's the point of that metric anyway? What is its intended purpose? Is it just swag? edit: guess I'll have to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Comment: You'll be surprise to see that 50% of the views occurred after [march 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140303014854/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page?)

Comment: No method of measuring impact is going to be perfect. There are always going to be outliers like these.

Comment: @TylerH et al, SE "views" is just an integer that grows, unlike votes, so, not even SE knows how many views a question had at any point of time.

Comment: @Braiam It might not "know" now, but it would be trivial to measure.

Comment: By tracking the view count when the answer is posted, that number can be subtracted from the total view count with minimal difficulty.

Comment: @user1122069:  Yes, but the question is how does one begin to track the view count of an answer.  If you count it when someone *hits* the page it's on, that's flimsy and inaccurate. What if the answer is buried on page 6? How much credit does one get for that view?  These and other wonderful edge cases have to be teased out before tracking answers can be viable.

Comment: @Makoto Count it by subtracting from the total view counts is a good beginning. Of course it is an over-estimation. More accurate counting is not possible due to the enormous amount of data to track/process/store, but it would be easy to reduce the threshold of "helpful answer" on questions with many up-votes. 5 upvotes out of 1 million views isn't that helpful. Various fair heuristics for that can be made, as that calculation is run not very often (once marked helpful, likely stored as a 1 value in DB)

Comment: 5 up-votes is considered helpful when the question sees up-vote counts like 18 and 23. That makes a total of 1/3 to 1/4 of total up-votes. On a question with 200 up-votes on the best answer, then a good count would be something like 50. And it would not be unfair or "expensive" to re-check each answer when the vote changes to see if it is no longer relatively helpful.

Comment: @user1122069:  I still think you're overthinking this.  If you think this work, why not post it as an answer instead of burying it in the comments?

Comment: @Makoto Its an rare case, which means it will be a low priority feature request. In that sense, very much over thought. Any good engineer could fix it if they want to spend the time.

Comment: @BalusC That post from July affirms the opinion that SO engineers are not interested in this metric. They must be very busy and who cares if some people's reach numbers are slightly inflated.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the late-answer effect, I think that a great deal of surprise comes from the sudden transition when an answer gets its 5th upvote, possibly long after being posted. An answer doesn't necessarily have to be posted late for it to take some time getting 5 votes. I've seen at least one other Meta post asking the same question, with the same conclusion of "oh, your answer just hit +5". If the "helpfulness factor" of an answer increased in a more gradual way instead of going from 0% at +4 to 100% at +5, the surprise factor would be reduced by quite a bit.

I don't have a concrete suggestion, just opening this avenue for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Since this was turned into a feature request, no need for this answer anymore!

---

This is not a bug. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32056298/1743880) of yours was upvoted today and the question was currently seen 1062039 times, i.e. a little more than 1 million times. Now sitting with 5 upvotes, it passed the threshold for being a helpful post. The rules for what is considered a helpful post are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here), quoted for convenience:

> - Questions
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - Answers - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - **Score at least 5** OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

This accounts for the huge gain of impact you noticed.

Comment: Nice, a trick for the impact count maybe! :) I thought that the view count for that answer made little sense since I had answered a lot later. But what about the 0 reach in meta site earlier(Now 7 due to this question)? Are the answers not counted towards the reach count?

Comment: @ManojKumar Probably because they were not "helpful post" as per the definition above.

Comment: Yes, the post is infinitely helpful, but I still see this as a bug. Those million views didn't appear between 17 August and now.

Comment: @Makoto Why 17 August? The post just crossed the impact thresold. It wasn't counted before.

Comment: Yes, but the answer in question didn't exist until that point.  I'm going to expound on this in an answer in a moment.

Comment: @Makoto Are you saying that the impact should count the number of views between the date the answer was posted and now?

Comment: That would make more sense.  Again, I'll be explaining this in a moment.

Comment: @Makoto OK, waiting for your answer, but the way I read the meta post, this is not how it was designed so I'm not sure we can tell it's a bug. It counts "Views of the parent question for answers" regardless of the date of the answer.

Comment: It's ready for your perusal.  If the code does that, then the code is legitimately doing what it's told, but what it's being told *feels* wrong.

Comment: @Makoto I agree that the metric is faulty. Perhaps a feature-request would be in order.