# The new "impact" card icons are too bold

Tags: discussion, design

[image] >>> [image]

*(the "before" image is stolen from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312031/how-did-i-impact-1-million-users-in-a-single-day))*

It's my opinion that they are too bold and stick out of the design a bit.

Were they changed as the result of a design issue? Was it determined that they look better than the originals?

I would suggest the original icons be returned, or these icons be altered to fit in better with the overall design.

Comment: All my attention was sucked there!

Comment: Ah, so they *did* change! I just so happened noticed they looked "off" earlier today but assumed it was just me.

Comment: It's just the colour of them rather than boldness - comparing the use of "bold" to its use with text.

Comment: They're not too "bold"; they're too dark. It was fine as it was before; I really don't understand why the devs are wasting time tinkering around with rubbish like this!

Comment: Part of your issue seems to be that your system is displaying solid black (#000000) text as dark gray (#343434).  Compare to what I see on my system: http://imgur.com/a/IVDB1  It's likely that your system text anti-aliasing settings are set incorrectly— _you should always be able to take a screenshot of solid-black text at normal body text sizes, open the screenshot in a image viewer/editor, and still find solid black pixels in the vertical & horizontal lines of letters!_

Comment: Can you post an image comparing what they looked like before? I don't see any problem with the current version.

Comment: Could be an unintended consequence of changing a CSS rule to fix/change/add something else @BoundaryImposition. The joys of CSS!

Comment: (Yes, Windows text rendering sucks, but it’s still too dark.)

Comment: What is your OS and browser version?

Comment: @Stijn the issue was 1y 7m ago: the change was probably rollbacked.

Comment: @Cœur perhaps, I figured since the OP edited the question today that they still have this issue.

Comment: @Stijn sorry, it's no longer reproducible; the edit was made by mistake